# Android Detect if on a highway

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

I want to write an app that notifies the driver if he or she is either on a highway or just local city driving. I am not sure if there is a way of achieving this using the maps API provided by google. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could check their speed... but I am not sure if you care if they are on a country road or something similar.

Comment: You need to have highways represented somehow. The only thing GPS does is to give you Earth coordinates, it does not know what is on these coordinates. I dont think the google api provides such a functionality. Search for a highway database and then make a function which checks if your current point is on one of them. Also the speed suggestion of MrZander is good idea I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a question somewhere else, and i belive that answer is exactly what you need.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16313808/578215)

But roughly you need to use Google geocoder api. Just get your latitude and longitude from gps api and use google geocoder api to get the address. That address will tell you the road you are currently on. After that, i am sure you can do the rest pretty easily.