# Android Geocoder doesn't detect highways / interstates?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using getThoroughwayfare() to get street names but when on a highway / interstate the method returns null. I couldn't find another method that could detect interstates. Has anyone been able to successfully detected interstates?

Thanks

Comment: Google maps supports some specific information which can be different on any location. And information support can be different because of your connection, gps or gsm network. Everytime you can not use all datas from any location.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, Its quite old question, but i think i answer for somebody else.

I too need to get information whether i was on interstate or not and Geocoder was of no help.
So i came across `Google geocode api` which gives plenty of information.

e.g

LatLng: 39.249121,-122.182131

And Url would be:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.249121,-122.182131&sensor=false

sensor is true in case you sending from mobile and false if using browser.

Now you can open the link and check the detailed reply for yourself, in those `json` objects, you will get a `type = route` and you will get **`I-5`** as the `short_name` of road you are on.